# Can gnu screen prompt for a title when a new window is created?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, gnu, dotfiles

There are a number of questions about automatically naming screen windows based on what's running in them.

But sometimes *why* you created the window is more important than *what* you're doing in it.

Can I set up gnu screen so it prompts me for a title whenever I make a new window?

Answer (score 1):

Easy. In your `.screenrc` file:

```
bind c  eval screen title
bind ^c eval screen title
```

The `eval` command evaluates each following commands in order (use quotes to embed spaces). Note that this is of limited flexibility, the commands don't block for user input - e.g. the `title` command is considered complete when the prompt is up. This is relevant if you're thinking of doing something with the `copy` command, which probably won't work out.

Answer (score 0):

This method works, but it requires a separate file.

Put this in your `.screenrc`:

`bind c source $HOME/.screenrc_create`

Then put this in `~/.screenrc_create`:

```
screen
title
stuff ^u
```